# What does it mean "a few weeks into"?

Tags: phrase-meaning, expressions, time

**What exactly does it mean *`"a few weeks into"`*?**

---

I've seen such translations into my L1 where it meant both

- right **after** starting sth ***`Two weeks into`***`the job, we had that vortex in the east river.`
- and right **before** the end of sth *`She left school`**`two weeks into`**`the semester.`* though here, it could as well mean "right **after** starting the semester"

---

Can it mean both depending on the context?

Comment: '_Two weeks into_' can roughly be interpreted as '_two weeks after_'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It always means "X days/weeks/whatever" **after the start of something.** It exploits a metaphorical image of how you "dive into" a job/semester/whatever, but think time instead of depth. Or you enter **into** a cave and go farther and farther—again, time instead of distance.